# leafletの地図上に近接する複数のアイコンを表示する際の処理

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, leaflet

当方、PHP、mysql、javascriptを使ったWEBアプリケーションを運用しています。
データベースには営業先の緯度・経度（地図上に表示するために使用）等のデータが入っています。
leafletというライブラリを使用して、ブラウザ上に地図を表示、地図上に営業先をアイコンとして表示しています。

この時に、同一の建物内や近接した場所に複数の営業先がある場合、アイコンが重なり合って、下に重なった営業先のアイコンが隠れてしまう問題が発生しています。
地図を拡大すれば下のアイコンが見える場合もありますが、全く同じ座標のアイコン同士は完全に重なってしまいます。
現時点では、完全に同じ座標のデータは座標を少しだけずらす等の対応をしていますが、あまりスマートではないように思います。
こうしたケースでの一般的な対処方法などありましたら、ご教示頂けないでしょうか。

宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

スタックオーバーフロー本家の類似質問で、プラグインによる解決方法が示されています。
[その1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22168558)、[その2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50813139)

上記回答やコメントからの引用となりますが、デモサイトを比較の上で目的に適したプラグインの導入をご検討されてはいかがでしょうか。

- [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) [デモ](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.388.html)
- [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet) [デモ](http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet/demo.html)
- [Leaflet.Marker.Stack](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.Marker.Stack) [デモ](http://ivansanchez.github.io/Leaflet.Marker.Stack/demos/color_ramps.html)